# FFMPEG Trying to restream a RTSP stream to HTTP

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have been trying top cobble something together to take a RTSP feed from a IP camera and re transmit it in HTTP.

I am trying to get the feed in to my home automation app which does not support RTSP. I want to point the HA app at the Linux server which will feed the stream.  I installed ubuntu 12.04, and FFMPEG.

Here is what I have come up with

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://us:pw@192.168.1.xx:554/Streaming/channels/301" http://localhost:1025/monitoring1.ffm
```

This is my ffserver.conf

```
indaddress 0.0.0.0
Port 1025
<Feed monitoring1.ffm>
File /tmp/monitoring1.ffm
FileMaxSize 50M
ACL allow 127.0.0.1
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>

<Stream monitoring1.mjpg>
Feed monitoring1.ffm
Format mpjpeg
VideoCodec mjpeg
VideoFrameRate 22
VideoBufferSize 80
VideoSize 1920x1088
NoAudio
</Stream>
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 1000.00 (1000/1)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://un:pw@192.168.1.55:554/Streaming/channels/301':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Server V3.1.1
    comment         : Media Server Session Description : standard
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.033000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 1k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
[tcp @ 0x1014060] TCP connection to localhost:1025 failed: Connection refused
http://localhost:1025/monitoring1.ffm: Input/output error
```

Comment: But is ffserv running? What does `sudo ss -plant|grep 1025` say? (It should show a listening process)

Comment: you are correct.  it was not running.  I found this command to try to start it ffserver -d -f /etc/ffserver.conf

But I get this result:
avserver version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  1 2016 14:24:20 with gcc 4.6.3
/etc/ffserver.conf:1: Incorrect keyword: 'HttpPort'
/etc/ffserver.conf:2: Incorrect keyword: 'HttpBindAddress'
/etc/ffserver.conf:6: Incorrect keyword: ' '
/etc/ffserver.conf:37: No URL found for <Redirect>
Incorrect config file - exiting.

Comment: How did you create that config file? Maybe it doesn't match that version of avserver?